# Bash: How to shorten long lines of a log file whilst keeping a fixed number of characters from beginning and end of each line?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a long log-file (ASCII text), which contains lines with different lengths going from some characters to many thousands characters. How can I shorten each long line with bash/linux commands?
Is it possible to replace the cutted text with something like "... N characters removed ..."?

My goal is to keep all lines with a length up to 100 characters untouched.
For all lines > 100 characters keep 40 characters from beginning, 40 characters from end, and insert "... N characters removed ..." in the middle where characters has been cut out (N replaced with number of removed characters).

Is this too complicated to do it with bash/linux commands?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: One thing to note, for lines that are 101 - 107 characters long, the resulting line will be even longer at 108 characters long because `... N characters removed ...` is 28 characters.

Comment: That's intended. So I can find shortened lines easier. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with [awk](/questions/tagged/awk)

```
awk '
(length > 100) {
    l=length
    $0 = substr($0,0,40) "..."l-80" Characters Removed..." substr($0,l-39)
}1' ./infile
```

#### Proof of Concept

```
$ cat ./infile
|- These are the first 40 characters --|0123456789012345678901234567890|-- These are the last 40 characters --|
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
9012345678901234567890
2345678901234567890
12345678901234567asdfasd9as98jf-a9jfa9uhf0sd9uhfas0dfadfa890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567aisfjds9dafa908sfj9asdjf9asdf89012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456asf9jasf-asjf0as8789012345678901234567890

$ awk '
     (length > 100) {
        l=length
        $0 = substr($0,0,40) "..."l-80" Characters Removed..." substr($0,l-39)
    }1' ./infile
|- These are the first 40 characters --|...31 Characters Removed...|-- These are the last 40 characters --|
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890...30 Characters Removed...1234567890123456789012345678901234567890
0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
9012345678901234567890
2345678901234567890
12345678901234567asdfasd9as98jf-a9jfa9uh...70 Characters Removed...1234567890123456789012345678901234567890
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890...59 Characters Removed...1234567890123456789012345678901234567890
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890...47 Characters Removed...sf9jasf-asjf0as8789012345678901234567890
```

Comment: @Gernot actually, we're both wrong. I had an off-by-1 error, it should be `l-39`.  I added an example line in the output that exemplifies that this is correct

Comment: @kvantour requirement was to shorten lines longer than 100, not 80. Also, wasn't certain if `length` by itself was non-standard, but it doesn't appear to be so; updated answer - thx

Comment: The message needs still a small correction: It's "..."l-80" Characters Removed...". From first line of your example  31 characters have been removed.

Comment: @Gernot ahh, was looking at the wrong place. Good catch, fixed

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue :-)

I believe your problem is: when you do something like `cat ... | cut -c...`, how can you append something to this?

Let me give you an example: I have a file, `test.txt`, which looks as follows:

```
Prompt>cat test.txt
version = 1.203
RAM/ABC/INDIA
RAJ/XYZ/DELHI
VIRAJ/FDS/
```

I can show different parts of lines, one after the other, like this:

```
Prompt>cat test.txt | awk '{print substr($1,1,1) "..." substr($1,3,1)}'
// print the first character, some constant string in between, and the third character
```

This gives following result:

```
v...r
R...M
R...J
V...R
```

So, putting all things next to each other in an `awk` script, like `{print <beginning> <middle> <end>}` gets the job done.

Comment: Thanks, but how to get the last n characters? The lengths of the lines varies.

Comment: The last characters can be found using `substr()` too: when you don't fill in the last parameter, the substring gets taken up to the last character. You'll need the length of the string to know where to start, which you can find using `length()` function.